# Not all Gmail address variations are being auto-forwarded

Tags: gmail

One of the things I love most about Gmail is the ability to use variations of your email address. You can append a plus or period anywhere and have it [automatically resolve back to your original email](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html).

But I'm noticing that auto-forward rules don't always work when you take advantage of this feature.

For instance, say you have **one@gmail.com** always forwarding to **two@gmail.com**. 
When I send an email to **o.n.e@gmail.com**, I see it in the inbox of **one@gmail.com** but not in the inbox of **two@gmail.com**.

Is this a bug? How do I get around this?

Comment: are you using a filter or the filtering feature in the accounts settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a filter you can set the filter to be the following:

```
to(*@gmail.com) as opposed to to(one@gmail.com)
```

That will catch any email that gets in your inbox, where one@ will only catch those to one@.

If you're using the settings > Fowarding and pop/imap it should forward anything in your inbox to that number.